# Getopts with curl bash

Tags: bash, shell, curl, scripting, getopts

I have got a question how to connect getopts with curl method in one function ? I am newbie in bash scripting. I will add my function below:

```
    addProject() {

        addProject_usage() { echo "addProject: [-p <arg>]" 1>&2; exit; }
        read OPTARG
        local OPTIND o p
        local OPTARG
        while getopts ":p:" o; do
            case "${o}" in
                p)
                    p="${OPTARG}"
                   ;;
                *)
                    addProject_usage
                ;;
            esac
        done
        shift $((OPTIND-1))


curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://adress.com/api/v3/projects?private_token=$token -d "{ \"name\": \"$p\" }"
}

addProject -p 
addProject
```

Thank you for any advice and help ! I dont know if i do it right but i don't think so .

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the script could be simplified a few:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#

addProject_usage() { echo "addProject: [-p <arg>]" 1>&2; exit; }

addProject() {

        local p
        p="myPdefault"

        while getopts ":p:" o; do
            case "${o}" in
                p)
                    p="${OPTARG}"
                   ;;
                *)
                    addProject_usage
                ;;
            esac
        done
        shift $((OPTIND-1))


curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://adress.com/api/v3/projects?private_token=$token -d "{ \"name\": \"$p\" }"
}

addProject -p foo 
addProject
```

Comment: Thank you pasaba for fast answer! 
What about making p as dynamic variable ? I edited the line p="myPdefault" to read p and when i want make a new Project i write:

    ./nameofscript.sh -p ( there should be name of $p but it doesnt work).

I have to press enter then write in blank line the name of project and it looks like:

    ./nameofscript.sh -p (press enter)
    nameofNewProject

[new project was added etc.]

    [root@root]: ...

Comment: @adamos: p="myPdefault" is the value that will be taken in case "-p" option is not provided (according to your usage specification, -p is optional). You can even delete this line. In this case, if -p is not provided, json in the curl query will be {"name": "" }.

Comment: @pasaba_por_aqui: Okey i got it but when i delete option variable p i mean: delete line: p="myPdefault"  and want to run script:

 ./myscriptname.sh -p blabla 

I got output : 
addProject: [-p <arg>]